# Adding script tool to ModelBuilder in ArcMap?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, modelbuilder, fields-attributes, python-script-tool

I have create a script and want to add it to the model I have provided. The code is:

```
import sys, string, os
import arcpy
import numpy
Table = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Field1 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Field2 = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(Table, Field1)
arcpy.AddField_management(Table, Field2 , "DOUBLE")
arcpy.CalculateField_management(Table,Field2,(numpy.mean(arr[Field1])))

out = arcpy.SetParameterAsText(4, Table)
```

However I want to select a field of a feature and calculate the mean value of that field and with the result of the mean continue the rest of the analysis in the model. I have create 3 Parameters, that 1th is a table and the input field and output field. However, when I import the script tool in the model , there is no output feature that I could link it to the rest of the model. How can I do that?
[image]

Comment: thank you for your feedback but the output is basicaly the same input. How to define it?

Comment: Check the help on arcpy's `SetParameter` & `SetParameterAsText`

Comment: I tried to define the output but still when I link it to the next tool in the model, it is not activated

Comment: Don't re-use a parameter number. Change it to 4.

Comment: still get the same result...

Comment: Shouldn't the output parameter be number 3 not 4?

Comment: Parameter should be 3.  Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot and description of your script tool parameters